# Make a Html.TextBoxFor look like a Label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to make the textbox in MVC 3 display like a label. The code i have still shows the border.

```
<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostcardsperWeek, new Dictionary<string, object>() { 
   { "id", "txtPostcardPerWeek" }, 
   { "readonly", "true" }, 
   {"class", "TextBoxAsLabel"} })
</p>
```

css:

```
.TextBoxAsLabel
{
   border: none;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the border the same color as your background.

Comment: i changed the border to border: #fff; but there is still the border on the textbox.

Comment: One thing, if i just do this; @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostcardsperWeek, new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel" })m then this works. But i would need to use new Dictionary<string, object> as i need to assign id for this textbox. I am using this textbox in jquery.

Comment: It worked. Chrome had cached the page, so I wasn't able to see the change. Thanks!!